# Allocating less than 4KB on Heap?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, malloc

**Please Notice my followup question under accepted answer.**

I just read about how translating from virtual to physical memory is done and I got an interesting question.

If the minimum size of frame in physical memory is 4KB why doesn't that say we can use heap for a minimum allocation of 4KB?
Or that if I wanted only 1 byte on heap then it allocates the whole frame of 4KB and the rest is kept unused (even that there is space for others)
Or It's split with other allocations/process since we have the offset field?

Comment: Don't forget that virtual addresses are mainly to *protect* processes from each other, and protection is on page level (ignoring that Intel x86 CPUs allow a lot of "interesting" combinations of pages and segments). Thus sharing a page between processes would make that impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int main()
{
    int* a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    int* b = malloc(sizeof *b);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)a);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)b);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x2164010
0x2164030
```

As you can see the allocated memory is within the same 4KB page (0x2164xxx), it has a 16-byte offset from the page and a 16-byte alignment).

Even if the mapping from physical to virtual addresses is done on some page size (e.g. 4KB), there may be several dynamic allocations within one mapped page.

Comment: Thank you, can you kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467458/translating-from-virtual-to-physical-memory

Comment: I think the original "Programming in C" by had an example `malloc` implementation. The fact that the C library has to manage those "sub-allocations" causes very strange effects when a write happens outside of the allocated range (In Linux `valgrind` is your friend then).

Comment: Thanks, but an interesting question is: can 2 processes share same frame (in case there is enough free space for both to use it)

Comment: @John There are ways to make shared memory between processes but that's another thing. In general NO - once a page is allocated to a process, only that process has access.